# Can't subscribe on a RxJava 2 Observable with TestSubscriber

Tags: android, rx-java2

Why is my compiler not allowing myself to subscribe on an `Observable` with a `TestSubscriber`?

Here's my code:

```
TestSubscriber<User> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
Observable.just(new User()).subscribe(testSubscriber);
```

And it's saying that it can't resolve method `subscribe` which is taking this parameter. But in all RxJava testing tutorials, they are using `TestSubscriber` without such problems. What can I do to test such `Observable`?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#testing

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is because `*Subscriber` are meant for `Flowable` while `Observable` uses the `*Observer` classes. This is because the reactive-streams standard reserves `Subscriber` for the fully compliant `Publisher` interface which `Flowable` implements.

Additionally with RxJava2 all reactive classes have a `.test()` method which will directly give you the appropriate testing object.

Answer (score 5):

For RxJava 1 → RxJava 2 migration, I've just replaced `TestSubscriber` with `TestObserver` to make `Observable#subscribe` call compile and work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `Observable` to `Flowable` if you want to test with `TestSubscriber` as follow:

```
TestSubscriber<User> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
Flowable.just(new User()).subscribe(testSubscriber);
```